# Python pandas concat intersect

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am struggling hard to get an intersection of two DataFrames in pandas.

```
In [22]: df1[0:10]
Out[22]: 
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0793oezim      3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Dashkent       6   7  15   4   4   1   1 NaN
Deniskildeev   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Krylova        3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Ksusha        12   2   4   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
Rusel1994      3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Sportsman     31   1   2   4   4 NaN NaN NaN
User495        6   7  15   3   4   3 NaN NaN
User498       12  10   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
User499        4  23   5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[10 rows x 8 columns]

In [23]: test = [df1[0:10],df1[8:10]]

In [24]: pd.concat(test,axis=0,join='inner')
Out[24]: 
               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0793oezim      3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Dashkent       6   7  15   4   4   1   1 NaN
Deniskildeev   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Krylova        3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Ksusha        12   2   4   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
Rusel1994      3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Sportsman     31   1   2   4   4 NaN NaN NaN
User495        6   7  15   3   4   3 NaN NaN
User498       12  10   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
User499        4  23   5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN
User498       12  10   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
User499        4  23   5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[12 rows x 8 columns]
```

All i want is to find an intersection of 2 DataFrames by index so only lines 8 through 10 appear in the result.

When i am changing axis to 1 the join='intersect' seems to start to work but the result is not what i really need:

```
In [25]: pd.concat(test,axis=1,join='inner')
Out[25]: 
          0   1  2   3   4   5   6   7   0   1  2   3   4   5   6   7
User498  12  10  4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  12  10  4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
User499   4  23  5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN   4  23  5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[2 rows x 16 columns]
```

as it adds the DataFrames contents together as it should do. Why does concat over axis=0 doesnt work? How to concatenate DataFrames by index?

Answer (score 2):

You want to try a merge. `concat` is better for gluing multiple frames together, merge will handle detection of overlapping rows and all that:

```
In [107]: df1
Out[107]: 
          index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0     0793oezim   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1      Dashkent   6   7  15   4   4   1   1 NaN
2  Deniskildeev   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3       Krylova   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4        Ksusha  12   2   4   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5     Rusel1994   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6     Sportsman  31   1   2   4   4 NaN NaN NaN
7       User495   6   7  15   3   4   3 NaN NaN
8       User498  12  10   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9       User499   4  23   5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[10 rows x 9 columns]

In [108]: df2
Out[108]: 
     index   0   1  2   3   4   5   6   7
8  User498  12  10  4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9  User499   4  23  5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[2 rows x 9 columns]

In [109]: pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
Out[109]: 
     index   0   1  2   3   4   5   6   7
0  User498  12  10  4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  User499   4  23  5   9 NaN NaN NaN NaN

[2 rows x 9 columns]
```

Notice that I reset the index (`df1.reset_index()`). Generally it's a good idea to have a unique index on your DataFrames if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various ways to solve my problem. The only one that seems to be working to get the right results is the function below:

```
def dataFrameMaskSplitbyIndex(df1,df2):
    mask1 = df1.index.isin(df2.index)
    mask2 = df2.index.isin(df1.index)
    tempdf = df1[-mask1]
    dfleft = tempdf.copy()
    tempdf = df2[-mask2]
    dfright = tempdf.copy()
    tempdf = df1[mask1]
    dfcenter = tempdf.copy()
    return dfleft,dfcenter,dfright
```

However i think that there might be some other less runtime expensive ways to solve my problem. If you have any do not hesitate to suggest them.